# How do I add external cdn links to a page served by cloudflare's "Workers & Pages" feature?

Tags: javascript, html, cdn, cloudflare-workers

I am using Cloudflare's "Workers & Pages" feature to create a simple html page and would like to add jquery and bootstrap cdn links.

```
 export default {
  async fetch(request) {
    const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <body>
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
          <p>This markup was generated by a Cloudflare Worker.</p>
        </body>`;

    return new Response(html, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
      },
    });
  },
};
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

How can I add these sources to the worker output?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just include the two sources in the html string you're returning?

Comment: @KevinB i was hoping for best practice using js.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`HTMLRewriter`](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/html-rewriter/) API, it's designed for making small modifications to HTML inside a Worker in a streaming way.